ERROR NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. [plugin angular-compiler]
I have the following error when I run the ng serve command:
error
This is my directory structure:
structure
app.component.html:
component html
app.component.ts:
component ts
app.module.ts:
module ts
fondo.service.ts:
enter image description here
What I'm doing wrong?

Please do not upload images of code/errors.

Please Add reference of ReactiveFormsModule in you app,module file or if using standalone then in your component.ts file
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OrderListComponent,
    OrderDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


Please do not upload images of code

Try adding FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in your imports.
Visit this link if you still having problems

Thank you for taking the time to answer the question. Your answer is correct and your link to an existing question is awesome. A code sample would make your answer ever better. Please check the answer provided by another user. I will upvote your answer since it's a very good attempt!
